# not recognized as a field

Tags: java, android, xml

Ok guys. So I attempted to upload an image to my drawable-hdpi file when i immediatly got an error in my source.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    counter = 0;
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
    sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

it wont recognize my activity_main all of a sudden and all the ids i had in it. Here is what my activity_main.xml looks like.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".StartingPoint" >

<TextView
    android:text="Your total is "
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/tvDisplay"
    android:textSize="45sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bAdd"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/bSub"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bSub"
    android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
    android:text="Subtraction" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bSub"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvDisplay"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
    android:text="Addition" />
```

Any ideas whats going on?

Comment: Are there any errors in your XML? Have you saved the file? Why aren't you closing the RelativeLayout tag?

Comment: nope there arnt any errors in my xml.I did close it but i didnt copy that part

Comment: What did you name the image you placed there? The exact name please, with any dots, and everything?

Comment: what is the name of the image that you save in the drawable?

Comment: Also did you try the clean command in Eclipse?

Comment: the image name was Character_Kaiser. and yes i attempted to clean multiple times. it keeps saying "splash is not recognized as a field"

Comment: capital letters are not acceptable in the image name. dont use it. use only small letters.

Comment: I changed it but i still get the error

Comment: and clean your project after rename the image

Comment: Yes i did that also. Im not a super noob. This error makes absolutely no sense though....

Comment: @user2118474 if you have an `import android.R`, take that out.

Comment: HOLY CRAP. That actually worked. THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU

Comment: if you actually made an answer though i wouldve set it as the accepted answer :(